# How to delete PrimeFaces UploadedFile temp file after processing?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces UploadedFile only exposes the InputStream, not the File itself. How can I delete it after processing the stream?

Comment: IMO You need close InputStream after processing. Nothing more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PrimeFaces uses Apache Commons FileUpload under the covers for this. It will create the file as a temporary file and hence the file will *already* be automatically deleted if there are no open `File` nor `InputStream` references to it when the Java Garbage Collector runs.

So if you can make absolutely sure that you close the `InputStream` after processing (in the `finally` block!), then you don't need to worry about cleanup.

Comment: I am closing it IOUtils.closeQuietly(in) but still not removing .temp files

Comment: @AZ_: they are not *immediately* removed but at intervals.

Comment: Yeah it deletes some after interval but Cache a lot of files till you don't restart server and I am uploading Gigs of Video so it is occupying my space until I restart Jboss and Restarting Jboss is not an option for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

It will remove some file but not all files until you Restart Server. I am working with JBoss 2.4.3 and Added Support of JSF 2.0 in Servlet 2.4. Please read complete detail on my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19534610/185022)

Well You need to write your own filter Read more about [FileCleaningTracker](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html#Resource_cleanup) on Apache website.

**Step 1:**

Extend your class with `org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter` and override following method

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpServletRequest);
        if (isMultipart) {
            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
                logger.fine("Parsing file upload request");

            FileCleaningTracker fileCleaningTracker = FileCleanerCleanup.getFileCleaningTracker(ContextConfigServlet.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
            DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            diskFileItemFactory.setFileCleaningTracker(fileCleaningTracker);

            if (thresholdSize != null)
                diskFileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(Integer.valueOf(thresholdSize).intValue());
            if (uploadDir != null)
                diskFileItemFactory.setRepository(new File(uploadDir));

            ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);
            MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(httpServletRequest, servletFileUpload);

            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
                logger.fine("File upload request parsed succesfully, continuing with filter chain with a wrapped multipart request");

            filterChain.doFilter(multipartRequest, response);

        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
```

**I have a Servlet that is called when context is initialized and getting ServletContext from there you can do like request.getSession.getServletContext...Please validate this**

**Step2:**

Goto your web.xml and add your filter calss in param

```
<filter-class>com.sf.server.filter.FileUploadFilter_</filter-class>
```

All done now it will remove all the temp files.