# Jboss 4 upgrade servlet version

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

As far as I know Jboss 4.0.x supports only serverlet version 2.4. Currently I have had to stick with Jboss 4 and need to make it support servlet 2.5 or higher (In order to integrate some frameworks as they support over servlet versions 2.5 and over).

Any one let me know is this possible? If so, what are the configurations which should be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JBoss 4.2.3 Servlet API 2.5 JSF 2.0 Hibernate 3.0 Support Added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534610/jboss-4-2-3-servlet-api-2-5-jsf-2-0-hibernate-3-0-support-added)